# Flutter "Mapping values are not allowed here" error when doing packages get

Tags: dart, flutter, yaml

I'm pretty sure that this is an error with YAML syntax, but I can't find it.

I recently added a new font to my project (Manrope) and now my `Flutter packages get` throws an error. Before I added the font it worked fine.

Here's the relevant part of the `pubspec.yaml`:

```
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
  - assets/

  fonts:
  - family: Hanken Grotesk
    fonts:
    - asset: fonts/HankenGrotesk-Regular.otf
    - asset: fonts/HankenGrotesk-Bold.otf
      weight: 700
    - asset: fonts/HankenGrotesk-SemiBold.otf
      weight: 600
    - asset: fonts/HankenGrotesk-Medium.otf
      weight: 500
    - asset: fonts/HankenGrotesk-Light.otf
      weight: 300
    - asset: fonts/HankenGrotesk-ExtraLight.otf
      weight: 200

  - family: Manrope
    fonts:
    - asset: fonts/manrope-regular.otf
    - asset: fonts/manrope-bold.otf
      weight: 700
    - asset: fonts/manrope-semibold.otf
      weight: 600
    - asset: fonts/manrope-medium.otf
      weight: 500
```

And here's the error message I get:

```
Error on line 65, column 12 of pubspec.yaml: Mapping values are not allowed here. Did you miss a colon earlier?
      fonts:
           ^

pub get failed (65)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're presentation of the relevant part makes it difficult to pinpoint line 65, as the sample is not that long.

I am pretty sure thought that the error is not in the presented part. As the error is caused by a value indicator (`:`) in column number 12 and in your samples the indicator after `fonts` is in position 10.

So search for a line where `fonts` is indented six positions instead of the four in the sample that you've included, and there is the error, probably caused by this over indentation.

(In general it is better to include the full text of the problematic file, if you cannot cut down the source for the problem)

Comment: actually I didn't save the document between edits and therefore Flutter packages get was always referring to not the current version of my pubspec.yaml. Very dumb mistake, so I'll just mark your answer as correct as it is pretty good advice

Answer (score 0):

A neat trick is that JSON is a subset of YAML, so if you ever have trouble figuring out the YAML indentation or syntax, just replace it with JSON, and you can mix-n-match.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You are Right. This is a problem with Yaml syntax. In Yaml, the Code is written in form of objects like in JSON so We have to be careful about the Indentation of the code each object is 2 spaces back to his child.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUKkO.jpg)

Comment: It would be better to put the correct code here as text rather than using a screenshot.

Comment: Right....! But thing i wants to show you is highlighted in the image can not be displayed with the code the indentation hierarchy ....